# Seaborn Pairplot with Dataframe vs CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

I have a dataframe in a Jupyter notebook and do a pairplot on it to get a bunch of plots against each other.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(df_merge)
```

Here is the pairplot as a result.

[image]

However, it plots the data incorrectly and in a non-aesthetic way. However, when I export this dataframe to a csv and then read it back into the program as a dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns
df_merge.to_csv('dataframe.csv')
x = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')
sns.pairplot(x)
```

Sns plots it fine and the correlations between variables can be seen but I have an unnecessary column called Unnamed which I don't need.

[image]

Does anyone know what could cause this issue and how I can go about correcting it without needing to export the dataframe as a csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the issue I was having was when I was changing the dataframe to a CSV and then changing it back to a dataframe, the values in the dataframe had a float64 type where as in my dataframe before they were all objects. Converting all the numerical columns to float before plotting the graph solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
df_merge.to_csv('dataframe.csv')
```

you write also the index of `df_merge` without a name. Then

```
x = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')
```

reads the index as `Unnamed 0` column. To fix this, either save the data frame without index:

```
df_merge.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
x = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')
```

or read the csv with index:

```
df_merge.to_csv('dataframe.csv')
x = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv', index_col=[0])
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I have no clue why directly putting the dataframe into pairplotting is giving me the messed plot though since both plots should be outputting the same thing and graphs as well. Do you know why this could also be the case?

Comment: Check if `df_merge` has string or categorical variables?

Comment: I don't believe it does. Will it change it I write the whole DF to a CSV and then reread it into the program? Both of those frames should be the same right? The one before writing it to a csv and the one after writing it to a csv?